# Using font from directory

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts

I need to use special font for my java project. I have to do this in java GUI JFrame. I don't know how to make JLabel with my font.
That's my font(.otf file) http://fontsgeek.com/fonts/DIN-1451-Std-Engschrift

Comment: Try "jlabel custom font" in da googles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do the trick (changing the font of your JLabel) :

```
JLabel text1 = new JLabel(); 
test1.setFont(new Font("FontName", Font.ITALIC, 100)); 
text1.setText("Your text here");
```

And if the font isn't on your system or you need to add it, look at the `createFont()`method

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#method_summary

```
createFont(int fontFormat, File fontFile)
Returns a new Font using the specified font type and the specified font file.
```

Try this and tell us if it worked !

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate, and I'm pretty sure the OP wants to use a custom font. You don't provide a code example for that.

Comment: I dont understand the second part. I dont know how to put exact directory here. i got this in C:\Windows\Fonts and font name is DIN 1451 Std Engschrift.otf. How to transfer this into my GUI frame?